# Is batch import option available?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

Is there any method to import data from mysql to elasticsearch,batch by batch?If yes,how to do it??
Because the bulk import seems to be a problem.When i import 191000 items,only a few are being imported.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.i have a column called ID1 in my mysql table.After the elasticsearch indexes the data,can i find how many ID1s have been indexed?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to. However, you should explain your problem in more details if you want people to be able to help you out.

Comment: Following is my River configuration.LC has 191000 rows.But not all are being indexed.This the problem i am facing.
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/mysql_table1/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LC",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "satyatma123",
        
        "sql" : "select * from test"
    }
    }'