# Elasticsearch to index RDBMS data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

These are three simple questions which was surprisingly hard to find definite answers.

1. Does ElasticSearch support indexing data in RDBMS tables ( Oracle/SQLServer/Informix) out of the box?
2. If yes, can you please point me to documentation on how to do it
3. If not, what are alternate ways (plugins like Rivers - deprecated) with good reputation

Comment: This might provide the answer you expect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639

Comment: @Val Interesting.. Thanks. I will check Logstash rightway.

Comment: @Val Logstash did the trick. thanks. I want to but I am not sure how to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Awesome!! You can still upvote the other answer since that's the one that helped you solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm surprised there isn't any solid answer as yet for this. So here's the solution. [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) directly gives us the ability to push data from a RDBMS into Elasticsearch.

Here's a link to a tutorial which tell you how to go about it. Briefly(all details in link 1), you simply need a JDBC driver for the relational database you'll be using (Postgres, MySQL etc) and make a config file specifying your input as the Relational Database and your output as Elasticsearch. You can also specify a cron which would allow you to keep updating one regular intervals.

- Here's the article which mentions the configuration and gets you started (See Example 2): https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin
- Here's the article which tells you how to configure the Cronjob as such: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_scheduling