# Elasticsearch Connector - Microsoft Exchange, SQL

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, connector, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

im currently evaluating searchsoftware study work.
I think, Elasticsearch is really good and cool, but currently im searching for connectors.

Specific Elasticsearch connectors for Microsoft Exchange, SQL etc.

My only results were Tools like SearchBlox, IntelliSearch and so on.

I hope you can help me, are there any Elasticsearch Connectors outside, which can connect Elasticsearch with Microsoft Exchange to index emails and SQL like MS SQL?

For SQL I only found those Rivers, but since they are deprecated there isnt a real solution, right? (https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating-rivers)

Greetings

Comment: This might be able to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639

Comment: @Val Thanks for you fast response. Yes, I just read that SQL should be able with JDBC over the logtash plugin. So that wouldnt be a problem anymore i think.
But I cant find anything about to connect the exchange server.

Comment: Here you can find the connection string and the driver library/class to use: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-input-jdbc-error-2-0-sql-server/33178