# Sync postgreSql data with ElasticSearch

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash

Ultimately I want to have a scalable search solution for the data in PostgreSql. My finding points me towards using Logstash to ship write events from Postgres to ElasticSearch, however I have not found a usable solution. The soluions I have found involve using jdbc-input to query *all* data from Postgres on an interval, and the delete events are not captured.

I think this is a common use case so I hope you guys could share with me your experience, or give me some pointers to proceed.

Comment: This answer might help (towards the end where I mention the Go/Python binlog solutions): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639

Comment: Thanks Val for the pointer. I found that post prior to asking this question. However I think now I can use the input-jdbc and do a little extra work to handle deleted data. Do you know how to setup Logstash to capture events from Postgres?

Comment: Uhm... I think that to work around the DELETE issue, I would not ever delete any record in my main database, and simply mark the records as `deleted`, and it will be reflected in ElasticSearch. When I feel like deleting stuff, I set a schedule to delete in both the main database and ES to delete everything with the deleted mark.

Comment: Yep, I was going to suggest the latter approach as well, just mark as deleted and update your timestamp, and the jdbc input will take care of it.

Comment: I would be happy to mark this as an answer if you are willing to compose it :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you need to also be notified on DELETEs and delete the respective record in Elasticsearch, it is true that the Logstash jdbc input will not help. You'd have to use a solution working around the binlog as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639)

However, if you still want to use the Logstash jdbc input, what you could do is simply soft-delete records in PostgreSQL, i.e. create a new BOOLEAN column in order to mark your records as `deleted`. The same flag would then exist in Elasticsearch and you can exclude them from your searches with a simple `term` query on the `deleted` field.

Whenever you need to perform some cleanup, you can delete all records flagged `deleted` in both PostgreSQL and Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 16):

You can also take a look at [PGSync](https://pgsync.com).

It's similar to Debezium but a lot easier to get up and running.

PGSync is a Change data capture tool for moving data from Postgres to Elasticsearch.
It allows you to keep Postgres as your source-of-truth and expose structured denormalized
documents in Elasticsearch.

You simply define a JSON schema describing the structure of the data in
Elasticsearch.

Here is an example schema: (you can also have nested objects)

e.g

> ```
> {
>     "nodes": {
>         "table": "book",
>         "columns": [
>             "isbn",
>             "title",
>             "description"
>         ]
>     }
> }
> ```

PGsync generates queries for your document on the fly.
No need to write queries like Logstash. It also supports and tracks deletion operations.

It operates both a polling and an event-driven model to capture changes made to date
and notification for changes that occur at a point in time.
The initial sync polls the database for changes since the last time the daemon
was run and thereafter event notification (based on triggers and handled by the pg-notify)
for changes to the database.

It has very little development overhead.

- Create a schema as described above
- Point pgsync at your Postgres database and Elasticsearch cluster
- Start the daemon.

You can easily create a document that includes multiple relations as nested objects. PGSync tracks any changes for you.

Have a look at the [github](https://github.com/toluaina/pgsync) repo for more details.

You can install the package from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pgsync/)

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Do you think you could expand on this a little bit, with some more info on what PGSync does and how it would help solve the original question? The best answers have minimal reliance on external links for support.

Comment: PGSync is a great piece of kit. It works well. You can even specify child tables/columns and relationships and have them merge into a single index.

Comment: PGSync is not working that well for us. When we create a new column in an existing table with data, it doesn't migrate data to ES. Should look for alternatives then?

Comment: @KhushalVyas Can you share more details on this or open a GitHub issue? Normally, when you add a new column to the schema.json you should ideally re-index.

Answer (score 8):

Please take a look at [Debezium](https://github.com/debezium/debezium). It's a change data capture (CDC) platform, which allow you to steam your data

I created a simple [github repository](https://github.com/YegorZaremba/sync-postgresql-with-elasticsearch-example), which shows how it works

[image]