# How to sync Mysql delete operation with logstash-input-jdbc?

Tags: elasticsearch, synchronization, logstash, delete-operator, logstash-input-jdbc

Now, I have been test insert, update operations with logstash-input-jdbc plugin, when the mysql changed(insert or update), elasticsearch also changed sync.
But when use mysql delete one row, the row exist in the elasticsearch, we can't delete it automatically.
Do you have any idea to resolve my problem?
Any help would be sincerely appreciate.
Thanks !

Comment: Apparently it is not supported by the plugin. I have found a discussion on elastic forum about this : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/delete-elasticsearch-document-with-logstash-jdbc-input/47490/4

Comment: Thanks, I'm laoyang360, you have been answer my question in discuss.elastic.co/t/…

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639

Comment: @Val, I already answer you at you link above. tks

Comment: Another answer that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813923/sync-postgresql-data-with-elasticsearch/35823497#35823497

Comment: Because there is no directly, efficient, good way to resolve the sync delete operation, I think your way of soft-delete is worth learning.