# SQL Server -> ElasticSearch (Data Consistency)

Tags: .net, sql-server, elasticsearch

http://damienbod.com/2014/09/22/elasticsearch-crud-net-provider/

https://www.elastic.co

Prerequisites / What I can do:

I have installed my node locally, using NEST and ElasticSearch.NET libraries (or a raw CURL command via Sense) I have created several documents in an appropriate index. I can retrieve the documents via the same libraries' "Search" method, or via Sense command.

What I'm looking for / What I don't 'want' to do:

I am now looking for a more "automated" way to synchronize data between SQL Server and ElasticSearch as the above approach seems tedious to manipulate into near real-time updates.

In the perfect world there would be a program that would ask me to specify the name of an index / type, which tables and columns (from SQL Server) would comprise the document and the frequency with which this program would run (to update add/update/delete) data.

Does such a piece of software exist?

If not, what are some examples of how others approach near real-time data consistency between these two product suites?

Comment: Either by using the logstash jdbc input or the JDBC importer tool (former is my preference). See this answer for more detailed info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639

Comment: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc

Comment: Are you looking for a way for data to not be duplicated in ElasticSearch? I have been experimenting with pulling data from a REST API which means I do not know what already exists in ElasticSearch and what doesn't. I have used fingerprinting in logstash and it seems to work the trick. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-fingerprint.html