# how to build river package?

Tags: maven, elasticsearch

I am trying to install mysql river that I found here...

https://github.com/scharron/elasticsearch-river-mysql

This will read from mysql binary log files and dump the data into elastic. I have installed the dependencies. i.e. pymysql, cherrypy and python-mysql-replication.

I did not understand how to install this plugin. It is mentioned to build using mvn clean package. How exactly this is done?

Comment: Is there any other easy to implement way to read and dump mysql binary files into elastic?

Comment: [Rivers have been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating-rivers) in ES 2.0. This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639