# ElasticSearch import data from mysql

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Today I have started working on Elastic Search, in my last project I have done the searching in Solr, and I was importing data from mysql and that was pretty simple.

Now I have to do same work in Elastic search, and successfully done the setup I have started working as per `"https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#quick-links"` but getting error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [2.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [5.0.0]

I am using Elastic Search version 5.0.0 and using the `"wget http://xbib.org/repository/org/xbib/elasticsearch/importer/elasticsearch-jdbc/2.3.4.0/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.0-dist.zip"` which is maximum available version.

Please suggest on this.

Comment: According to the link provided, in the given matrix there you could only use the importer till the ES version of 2.3.4, where as you're using the latest.

Comment: @Kulasangar so how to do this in 5.0.0.

Comment: Simply you wanted to import data from your mysql db to your index in ES?

Comment: Yes, and any data updated, deleted vai any other program to database then my ES data updated like Solr delta query doing.

Comment: I'm not sure how Solr delta works. But you could upload MySQL data to your index using `logstash` and update it using a scheduler.

Comment: Ok, I will try the logstash also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128613/discussion-between-kulasangar-and-deepesh-uniyal).

Comment: This answer should help also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jdbc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc) plugin in your `logstash` config in order to upload data to your index and then make sure you could keep updating it by adding a scheduler according to your need.

Your `logstash` config could look like this:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "select * from table1"
    type => "table1"
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "testdb"
        document_type => "%{type}"   # <- use the type from each input
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
}
```