# Synchronize SQL Server and Elasticsearch

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, data-synchronization

What is the approach of synchronizing SQL Server and elastic search, There is SQL Server as main database, and elasticsearch should be inform about any new added/updated/deleted records.

I know there was river which is deprecated, and I know  logstash for exporting data from SQL Server to elasticsearch, but these can not resolve the issue.

Could anyone help?

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639

Answer (score 0):

> I know logstash for exporting data from SQL Server to elasticsearch

Yes this is possible. Why are you saying

> but these can not resolve the issue.

?

Anyway, my advice is to change the application layer if you can, and index the documents in the same "transaction" as you are modifying your data in the database.

I described this in a [blog post](http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2015/05/09/advanced-search-for-your-legacy-application/).

Comment: Thank you for your response, Becuase of getting real time changes, and one important thing, you think that  there are multiple local SQL server database and one central SQL Server database, also each local database has own ES and also central, and use SQL Server replication for integrating data into central database. in this case, how can resolve it in application layer?!!!!

Comment: I don't know and I probably don't understand the question TBH. But did you read my blog post?