# why sync sql with elasticsearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch

Some architectures keep data in an SQL database and sync it with Elasticsearch to support some advanced search options that Elasticsearch is good at, but if they do that, what is the reason to keep the data in the SQL database? After all, you can create, read, update and delete in in ES also.

Thanks.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630227/4604579

Answer (score 0):

I can see reasons for keeping it in SQL if your architecture was built around for example you might be using an MVC framework like Laravel or Django that plays nice with sql and the relational db architecture.