# Sync Elasticsearch Postgresql on a Springboot application

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, search, architecture, search-engine

I have Postgresql as my primary database and I would like to take advantage of the Elasticsearch as a search engine for my SpringBoot application.

**Problem**: The queries are quite complex and with millions of rows in each table, most of the search queries are timing out.

**Partial solution**: I utilized the materialized views concept in the Postgresql and have a job running that refreshes them every X minutes. But on systems with huge amounts of data and with other database transactions (especially writes) in progress, the views tend to take long times to refresh (about 10 minutes to refresh 5 views). I realized that the current views are at it's capacity and I cannot add more.

That's when I started exploring other options just for the search and landed on Elasticsearch and it works great with the amount of data I have. As a POC, I used the Logstash's Jdbc input plugin but then it doesn't support the DELETE operation (bummer).
[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477095/elasticsearch-replication-of-other-system-data/34477639#34477639) the soft delete is the option which I cannot take because:
A) Almost all the tables in the postgresql DB are updated every few minutes and some of them have constraints on the "name" key which in this case will stay until a clean-up job runs.
B) Many tables in my Postgresql Db are referenced with CASCADE DELETE and it's not possible for me to update 220 table's Schema and JPA queries to check for the soft delete boolean.

The same question mentioned in the link above also provides [PgSync](https://github.com/toluaina/pgsync) that syncs the postgresql with elasticsearch periodically. However, I cannot go with that either since it has LGPL license which is forbidden in our organization.

I'm starting to wonder if anyone else encountered this strange limitation of elasticsearch and RDMS.

I'm open to other options rather than elasticsearch to solve my need. I just don't know what's the right stack to use. Any help here is much appreciated!

Comment: did you end up using Logstash or PgSync?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Then on the diagram it will look like this]

In service A, where the relational database is connected, it is necessary to implement an event listener for changing, deleting, updating data.

Then, when there is a change in data that needs to be deleted or updated, for example, the event listener is called by the producer, which distributes the data in a queue and sends it to a certain topic, depending on where the data needs to be written.

In service B, in the consumer, the queue is listening, which takes the necessary data and writes it to elastic search.