# Real time copy of data with TTL Persistance from Cassandra to ElasticSearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, cassandra, logstash, ttl

I have Cassandra DB with data that has TTL of X hour's for every column value and this needs to be pushed to ElasticSearch Cluster real time.

I have seen [past posts on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364996/real-time-migration-of-data-from-mysql-to-elasticsearch) that advise using tools such as LogStash or pushing data directly from application layer.

However, How can one preserve the TTL of the data imported once the data is copied in **ES Version >=5.0**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was once a field called `_ttl`which has been [deprecated in ES 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_literal__timestamp_literal_and_literal__ttl_literal_deprecated) and [removed in ES 5.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#_literal__timestamp_literal_and_literal__ttl_literal).

As of ES 5, there are now two official ways of preserving the TTL of your data. First make sure to create a TTL field in your ES documents that would be set to the creation date of your row in Cassandra + the TTL seconds. So if in Cassandra you have a record like this:

```
INSERT INTO keyspace.table (userid, creation_date, name)
VALUES (3715e600-2eb0-11e2-81c1-0800200c9a66, '2017-05-24', 'Mary')
USING TTL 86400;
```

Then in ES, you should export the following document to ES:

```
{
    "userid": "3715e600-2eb0-11e2-81c1-0800200c9a66",
    "name": "mary",
    "creation_date": "2017-05-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ttl_date": "2017-05-25T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Then you can either:

A. Use a cron that will regularly perform a [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/docs-delete-by-query.html) based on one of your `ttl_date` field, i.e. call the following command from your cron:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/_delete_by_query -d '{
  "query": { 
    "range": {
      "ttl_date": {
        "lt": "now"
      } 
    }
  }
}'
```

B. Or use time-based indices and insert each document in an index matching it's `ttl_date` field. For instance, the above document would be inserted in the index named `your_index-2017-05-25`. Then with the [curator tool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html) you can easily [delete indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/ex_delete_indices.html) that have expired.

Comment: Thank You Val for answer. It is helpful.